# Error: Minified React error #321 on Wordpress custom block plugin

Tags: wordpress, react-hooks, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

Whenever I write a useEffect() inside a component function of my block plugin, the edit page goes blank and the console logs the message:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
at Object.it (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:43163)
at e.useState (react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:10899)
at Prompt (Prompt.js:5:35)
at N (element.min.js?ver=3dfdc75a0abf30f057df44e9a39abe5b:2:9552)
at U (element.min.js?ver=3dfdc75a0abf30f057df44e9a39abe5b:2:10502)
at N (element.min.js?ver=3dfdc75a0abf30f057df44e9a39abe5b:2:9284)
at lr (blocks.min.js?ver=658a51e7220626e26a92a46af5c2e489:3:111294)
at blocks.min.js?ver=658a51e7220626e26a92a46af5c2e489:3:137935
at xn (blocks.min.js?ver=658a51e7220626e26a92a46af5c2e489:3:138073)
at blocks.min.js?ver=658a51e7220626e26a92a46af5c2e489:3:139086
```

The component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Prompt(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "http://my-site-test.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields[]=title"
      );

      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      JSX...
    </>
  );
}

export default Prompt;
```

I tried to delete node_modules and reinstall to no avail…

Comment: If you remove the `useEffect` and `useState` in the code shown, you don't get the React error anymore, I assume?

Comment: Hey friend, thanks for the reply... but that was not the real problem

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is in `my-plugin/src/index.js` — `wp.blocks.registerBlockType`'s 'save' property only allows static `HTML` to be returned (so it can be stored in the database within the content) and I was trying to insert a React component into it.

Since I want a dynamic block on the front-end, I have to load a `register_block_type` in `my-plugin/index.php` to render my component.

**EDIT** You actually can add React directly in the save attribute if you have specified `script` when registering your block in the `PHP` main file (or in your `block.json` file.

Comment: Very helpful! Could you give an example of what that code would look like?

Comment: How to specify script when registering your blobk in the PHP file or in blok.json?

Comment: @kamisama42 just remove all the hooks inside the the `save` function

Answer (score 0):

I used to encounter this error and figured out the reason. If your block is a static block, meaning that your `save` function return some thing. That can be a pure HTML markup or contain some React components. But remember, these React components must be resolved as **static HTML**, that means you are not allowed to put any kind of `hooks` inside it.